# Chart.js letter spacing very awkward

Tags: chart.js

[image]

As shown above, the letter spacing in my Chart.js is very large. I have no clue as to why it is that way - here is my config:

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: lineChartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [
                            {
                                gridLines: {
                                    color: '#354657',
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                        xAxes: [
                            {
                                gridLines: {
                                    color: '#354657',
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            });
```

The letter spacing is this large no matter what font I use. Is there a method to reduce it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `fontSize` property in the options like this `xAxes: [{
                   ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10
                   }
                  }]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've resolved this or not yet, but thought I'd give you a heads up. I had a similar question and linked it to this, the answer for me was removing the `devicePixelRatio` setting that I had set, but given you have the problem in the browser version (I imagine), have you tried setting `devicePixelRatio = 2`? It might be the fix for this.