# How can I tighten letter spacing on labels with ChartJS?

Tags: canvas, chart.js, node-canvas

I'm trying to draw a chart using https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas but the labels have a strange letter spacing and they look too spaced out.

Below is an image of a chart drawn with chart.js on the browser on the left and a chart drawn with chartjs-node-canvas on the right. You can see the labels are the only thing that's really throwing it off.

I found a similar issue here [Chart.js letter spacing very awkward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229156/chart-js-letter-spacing-very-awkward) but no answers on that question so here's hoping someone has a solution.

[image: left chart browser drawn, right chart chartjs node canvas drawn]

I've tried tweaking `canvas.styles.letterSpacing` of the canvas directly in the node library, but it hasn't worked so far.

Anyone else with any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying countless of different things, I found out that the issue was in the `devicePixelRatio` setting I was using to replicate the config from the browser version. This was originally set to `2` in the browser version, I removed it from the node.js version and now the graph looks as expected (or at least close to):

[image: corrected chart]

Documenting this here in case someone else stumbles upon this question or issue in the future.